# On super-logarithmic Collatz numbers

Tags: asymptotics, conjectures, collatz-conjecture

The [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) (or 3n + 1 conjecture) is a conjecture in mathematics that concerns a sequence defined as follows: start with any positive integer n. Then each term is obtained from the previous term as follows: if the previous term is even, the next term is one half the previous term. Otherwise, the next term is three times the previous term plus 1. The conjecture is that no matter what value of n, the sequence will always reach 1.

We denote by $collatz(n)$ the number of steps it takes to reach $1$ from $n$ (its *delay*).

Clearly, $collatz(n)\ge \log_2 n$ -- but by how much?

While the conjecture is still open, do we know any integer sequences with a super-logarithmic delay? Namely:

> **Is there a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $\mathit{Collatz}(a_n)=\omega(\log a_n)$?**

What about the weakest bound, which is probably true:

> **Is there a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $\mathit{Collatz}(a_n)=\log_2 a_n + \omega(1)$?**

---

From simulating *many* ($> 10^{12}$) random numbers (not in a uniform manner) between $1$ and $2^{9999}$, it seems that $\mathit{Collatz}(n)$ may be bounded by $50\log_2 n$.

> Is there an $n$ for which $\mathit{Collatz}(n) \ge 50\log_2 n$?

Comment: Judging by how massively that bound overestimates the length of sequences for small numbers, it's unlikely to be exceeded by any small numbers. E.g. the first long sequence is for the number 27, which is I think 41 steps long but your upper bound is 237 steps. So you may quickly get your answer by testing for much larger numbers.

Comment: @RobertFrost - this bound may be quite tight (and yes, for much larger number); for example for $n= 0b101110100101011010101101010001111111111110101010011101111$, $Collatz(n)=2254\approx 40\log_2 n$.

Comment: Unfortunately the long outliers tend to be quite rare and isolated so it's difficult to test without sampling every number in the range. I vaguely remember the distribution of sequence lengths almost perfectly matches some probability distribution so if you can identify that and then parametrise it according to some sample you should get some indication of the accuracy of this bound.

Comment: @RobertFrost- I agree that very long delays are uncommon and hard to find. Nevertheless, it seems easy to find millions of numbers for which $Collatz(n)\ge 5\log_2 n$ for example, and even $Collatz(n)\ge 10\log_2 n$ is quite abundant. This is why I asked if we can construct an explicit sequence  $\{a_n\}$ such that $Collatz(a_n)=\log_2 a_n + \omega(1)$. I believe that this should be possible as in every range I've tried I always found larger delays quite easily.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you will find the answer to your question in Lagarias, J. C.; Weiss, A. The $3x + 1$ Problem: Two Stochastic Models. Ann. Appl. Probab. 2 (1992), no. 1, 229--261. doi:10.1214/aoap/1177005779.